# What's the optimal method to solve for the top eigenvectors of a very large, real, symmetric matrix of limited rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

Consider a real symmetric matrix of dimension N~10^5 and rank m~2000.  What is the most efficient algorithm for determining the top m eigenvectors?  If the answer isn't obvious, are there existing routines for this in languages like MATLAB or Python?

Comment: Take a look at "Efficient Algorithms for Large-scale Generalized Eigenvector Computation and Canonical Correlation Analysis" https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.03930

Comment: That paper deals with generalized eigenvectors and CCA.  I don't see a solution to this problem in there unless I'm missing something.

Comment: As a first though (didn't test it), I would go with QR decomposition with `economy` option both in matlab or scipy. Then work with the smaller square matrix.

Comment: How do you know that the matrix has low rank? If you happen to know already a low-rank decomposition, then the problem is much easier.

Comment: We know the matrix is of low rank because it measures the covariances of a signal between N elements, but the signal only has m degrees of freedom.

Comment: Is the matrix dense?

Comment: @user149661 Are the inputs exact, or are there measurement errors that may spoil the low-rank property?